# Combine javafx 2 ListView and GridPane features

Tags: java, listview, layout, javafx-2, javafx

My target is to display an abbreviation list with two entries per line: the abbreviation and the corresponding long version. For a nice layout I used a `GridPane` because of the vertical alignment over all entries - it's nice to read.

But I also want to scroll to the clicked abbreviation and set the focus on it like in a `ListView` version of it.

For example the # on page links in good old HTML. Is there another `javafx` layout element I miss to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a provided control that will work for the specific scenario you are describing. However, I think one of these options might work for you...

1. Use the TableView control and add two columns for the information you want to show (one for the abbreviation and another for the long version). TableViews also have the scrollTo and setFocus functionality you're looking for. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) is a good resource to get you started with the Tableview control. You can also style the Tableview with CSS to look less like a table and more like a list if thats what your intention is.
2. The second option is to set a custom cell factory on your ListView that builds custom cells using HBoxes, VBoxes, Labels, etc. to achieve your desired look. You would also want to use the cell factory to populate each ListView cell with an object that contains both the abbreviated text and long version text. A couple good resources, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661500/javafx-listview-item-with-an-image-button), [2](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/05/implement-javafx-listview-for-custom.html)

Although I think both option will work fine, I would suggest option 1 since in option 2 you are sort of building a table type structure anyway. I hope this is helpful!