# Embedding custom HBox in FXML ListView

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to have a ListView of HBoxes and am currently trying to do it using FXML. This is somewhat related to [JavaFX - ListView Item with an Image Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661500/javafx-listview-item-with-an-image-button), but in bluevoxel's answer, the HBox is implemented in code.

How can I do it with FXML?

In more details:
[image]

DayBox is a HBox with a label, and below it is a ListView. In my main application, there is a ListView of these DayBoxes.

Comment: I have a simple answer for you: don't try to achieve something that's not meant to be done.

Comment: @Roland what do you mean by that? Can you suggest alternative ways to achieving this then? The reason for using FXML is so that I can do styling easier than if I do it with just code.

Comment: Why do you want to put a custom component into a ListView via FXML? A ListView contains a list which is a collection of an arbitrary number of items which may change during runtime. Just add your component via plain Java to the ListView.

Comment: @Roland You mean there's no possibility to using FXML to style the custom components?

Comment: Yes, you can use FXML to style custom components. Only adding them to the list view isn't possible inside the FXML.