# ListView with Delete Button on every row in JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx

How can I create `ListView` with delete button on every row and delete button action in JavaFX?

[image]

Comment: How can i set action to delete a row?

Comment: Anyone here who can help me?

Comment: Create custom `ListCell` and `setCellFactory()` of your `ListView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an SSCE that was mainly based on [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661500/javafx-listview-item-with-an-image-button).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SO extends Application {
    static class XCell extends ListCell<String> {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Label label = new Label("");
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Button button = new Button("Del");

        public XCell() {
            super();

            hbox.getChildren().addAll(label, pane, button);
            HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
            button.setOnAction(event -> getListView().getItems().remove(getItem()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

            if (item != null && !empty) {
                label.setText(item);
                setGraphic(hbox);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");
        ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>(list);
        lv.setCellFactory(param -> new XCell());
        pane.getChildren().add(lv);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The most important modification is this line

```
button.setOnAction(event -> getListView().getItems().remove(getItem()));
```

where the item that this cell represents is removed from the items list of the `ListView`.

Comment: Is there really a need for the `lastItem` field? Your button's action handler can just do `getListView().getItems().remove(getItem())` (and in fact `lastItem` is always the same as `getItem()`).

Comment: You are totally correct (too dumb copy pasting from my side). Thanks for pointing out.