# Swipe JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, listview, scroll, javafx-8

everyone. I got the following task: I need to implement swipe for listview. I've tried to use example from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537548/javafx-listview-with-touch-events-for-scrolling-up-and-down) ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723970/5350482) answer). But it doesn't work for me. I try to use `ScrollEvent` for this purposes. Here my code:

```
public class SwipeEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
private final ListView<Long> list;
private double x;
private double y;

public SwipeEventHandler(final ListView<Long> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

@Override
public void handle(final MouseEvent e) {
    final EventType<? extends MouseEvent> type = e.getEventType();
    if (type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
        set(e);
    } else if (type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
        final double deltaX = getX() - getX(e);
        final double deltaY = getY() - getY(e);
        set(e);
        final EventTarget source = e.getTarget(); // cell
        final EventTarget target = (EventTarget) e.getSource(); // listview
        final ScrollEvent event = new ScrollEvent(
                source,
                target,
                ScrollEvent.SCROLL,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                e.isShiftDown(),
                e.isControlDown(),
                e.isAltDown(),
                e.isMetaDown(),
                false,
                false,
                deltaX,
                deltaY,
                0,
                0,
                ScrollEvent.HorizontalTextScrollUnits.NONE,
                deltaX,
                ScrollEvent.VerticalTextScrollUnits.NONE,
                deltaY,
                1,
                null);
        Event.fireEvent(target, event);
    } else {
        setX(0);
        setY(0);
    }
}

private double getY(final MouseEvent e) {
    return e.getSceneY();
}

private double getX(final MouseEvent e) {
    return e.getSceneX();
}

private void set(final MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.printf("%s-%s %s-%s %s\r\n", getX(), e.getSceneX(),
            getY(), e.getSceneY(), e.getEventType().getName());
    setX(e.getSceneX());
    setY(e.getSceneY());
}
// getters and setters
```

But nothing happens when I 'Drag' over listview. Could anyone explain me what i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

When I said "nothing happens" I mean that my code called, but no list scroll performed. I've tried to change source, target, coordinates to another values, bit I didn't found right combination of this params.

Comment: What does this "nothing happens" mean? Is your code even called?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, add update section for your question. Thanks for reply

Comment: I'm guessing that nothing happens is because your reference answer related to vertical scrolling - something which ListView supports natively. I don't think your list view supports swipes natively.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i need swipes by mouse drag. So, I need some solution which translate "mouse move" to scroll move or some another... any solution=)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user swipes on the list? Have you tried registering a handler for scroll events with the list view? It's not really clear why you are translating this to a scroll event anyway; why not just use the drag event to initiate the behavior you want?

Comment: I think what you intend to do is a list where each item is swipable and shows some actions. This means what you actually want is a list with custom cellfactory ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691104/7470253) is a pretty good start), where each item should support a [SwipeEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/SwipeEvent.html) (or possibly ScrollEvents produced as a result of following the swipe).

Comment: I think I give bad explanation what I want. I want work with list such as with list ob the phobe, but by mouse for desktop. I couldn't found any implementation of swipe directly (my listeners for `onSwipeUp()` etc. was ignored). So, I've tried to convert `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED` event to scroll. Of course, handler, described before, added to my `ListView`.

Comment: @James_D, what do you mean by  "just use drag event"? If drag of cells than how it can be in listview? If you mean `ListView` than I can't understand how it can work at whole. Simply, my question is how to drag list cells by mouse click and drag, not by mouse wheel.

Comment: I just wondered why you were firing a scroll event. Presumably you want something to happen when the user does this, right? (You still haven't told us what.) So why not just implement the code for whatever it is you want to happen in your mouse drag listener, instead of firing a scroll event (and then presumably you are going to register a listener for the scroll event???). Anyway, the strategy outlined by @M.Prokhorov is the correct one; register listeners with each cell, using a cell factory.

Comment: @James_D, that's assuming he does want the swipe. I'm still not clear of behavior he wants. Maybe it's just list scrolling via touch events, like on mobile (but with JavaFx for whatever reason).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes, I subsequently wondered whether he was referring to "panning", rather than "swiping". Panning is supported directly in scroll panes, but not in virtualized controls that manage their own scrolling, AFAIK.